# How to destroy chart object in order to change chart data dynamically (Chart.js)?

Tags: javascript, object, chart.js, destroy

I display a set of charts in `<canvas class="evaluator_chart"></canvas>`

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($eval_list); $i++) {
   echo '<canvas class="evaluator_chart"></canvas>';
}
```

and try to change their content/data dynamically by clicking on links.
**I am unable to properly destroy the chart object.** Either all charts are displayed but the data is not changed, or the data is changed but not all charts are displayed (see sample below).

```
    const myCanvas = document.querySelectorAll('.evaluator_chart');

    for (let i = 0; i < myCanvas.length; i++) {
        // split chart data by individual charts
        const data   = [];
        const labels = [];
        for (let x = i; x < by_eval_values.length; x+= myCanvas.length) {
            labels.push(by_eval_labels[x]);
            data.push(by_eval_values[x]);
        }
        const dataByEval = {
           ...
        };

        // destroy previous chart object
        if (window.byEval) window.byEval.destroy();

        // create chart object
        let ctx = myCanvas[i].getContext('2d');
        window.byEval = new Chart(
            ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: dataByEval,
            options: options
        });
    }
```

Not sure whether the whole construction is correct. Thanks in advance for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - the Destroy part moved before the cycle and destroyed all objects there at once